# VBA Userform Iif Calculation not calculating correctly

Tags: excel, vba

Hi there I have a userform with 8 combobxes that I have coded as such

```
With Cbx1_1
.AddItem "N/A"
.AddItem "Yes"
.AddItem "No"
End With

With Cbx1_2
.AddItem "N/A"
.AddItem "Yes"
.AddItem "No"
End With , etc,etc,etc
```

now I am trying to get a percentage in OUTBX5(TextBox) that will give me the number of "Yes" over the number on applicable Questions. 
This has brought me to the code :

```
 Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()
 a = IIf(Cbx1_1.Value = "Yes", 1, 0) + IIf(Cbx1_2.Value = "Yes", 1, 0)_
 + IIf(Cbx1_3.Value = "Yes", 1, 0) + IIf(Cbx1_4.Value = "Yes", 1, 0)_
 + IIf(Cbx1_5.Value = "Yes", 1, 0) + IIf(Cbx1_6.Value = "Yes", 1, 0)_
 + IIf (Cbx1_7.Value = "Yes", 1, 0) + IIf(Cbx1_8.Value = "Yes", 1, 0)_

 b = 8 - IIf(Cbx1_1.Value = "N/A", 1, 0) + IIf(Cbx1_2.Value = "N/A", 1, 0)_
 + IIf(Cbx1_3.Value = "N/A", 1, 0) + IIf(Cbx1_4.Value = "N/A", 1, 0)_
 + IIf(Cbx1_5.Value = "N/A", 1, 0) + IIf(Cbx1_6.Value = "N/A", 1, 0)_
 + IIf(Cbx1_7.Value = "N/A", 1, 0) + IIf(Cbx1_8.Value = "N/A", 1, 0)_

 OUTBX5.Text = Format(a / b, "00%")
```

Now when I select Yes or No in all the boxes I get the correct Answer.
However when I leave some of the combo boxes as N/A the calculation goes pear-shaped, for example if all the boxes are checked as yes I get 100% as a result, by changing 1 of the combo boxes to N/A the result should be 100% but the result I get is 78%.

Can someone tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: I imagine you meant to use `-` rather than `+` in all the parts of the `b = ` statement.

Comment: Thank you... lol. I saw that just as the notification came through